# Multiple AJAX POST requests in same session 

Tags: ajax, jquery

I am trying to finish my video view count functionality. I am sending an AJAX post request to create a video view after the video has finished playing. I have a video playlist container that loads new videos via jquery. When I load the page, my AJAX POST call works for the first video in the playlist however, when I click on another video the AJAX request is not recognized.

This is the code I am calling to create the view. The "$('#video1').data('videoId'" loads the video's ID.

```
jwplayer().onComplete(function(event) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '<%= create_media_view_path %>',
        cache: false,
        data: { m: $('#video1').data('videoId') }


    });
```

Is there anything special I need to do to make multiple post requests? Do I need to reload this function each time a new video is selected?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up finding the fix... All I needed to do was load the onComplete function again for every video. I simply copied and pasted it into my jquery video container to be reloaded everytime a video is clicked.